# Could not build Docker image WindowsServerCodre on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to build some Windows docker images on Azure Devops. However, during the last step I get:

> re-exec error: exit status 1: output: time="2018-10-29T14:26:32Z" level=error msg="hcsshim::ImportLayer failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3) layerId=\\?\C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\e5d6a8d03464d02106a603b183b1ea47ad9fdd910a7dc1fdf19f605ec343b9cb flavour=1 folder=C:\ProgramData\docker\tmp\hcs934975059"
>
> 2018-10-29T14:26:34.2133323Z hcsshim::ImportLayer failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3) layerId=\?\C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\e5d6a8d03464d02106a603b183b1ea47ad9fdd910a7dc1fdf19f605ec343b9cb flavour=1 folder=C:\ProgramData\docker\tmp\hcs934975059

The weird thing is that I have the **exactly same branch** on my personal account and it works! It only fails for conan-io organization!

What I could do to fix it?

It's possible to check all *windowsservercore* [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/windowsservercore/). I can't use 1709 or 1803 because of my environment.

Logs are available here:
[success] https://dev.azure.com/uilianr/conan-devops/_build/results?buildId=92&view=logs
[failing] https://dev.azure.com/conanio/conan-docker-tools/_build/results?buildId=28&view=logs

Docker recipes are here (same file on both repositories):
[uilianries] https://github.com/uilianries/conan-docker-tools/blob/feature/docker-windows/msvc_14/Dockerfile
[conan-io] https://github.com/conan-io/conan-docker-tools/blob/feature/docker-windows/msvc_14/Dockerfile

Comment: Try to put `ltsc2016` tag instead of specific build for windows server core. There is definitely issue with mutli OS build on VSTS and lack of concise plan from Microsoft how to handle different kernel base images.https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/issues/182

Comment: @GregorySuvalian thanks for you advice, I updated to ltsc2016 but unfortunately didn't work. Also I tried 1803 but only 2016 is supported according the host version.

Comment: You have to run in hyper-v isolation to run different base image on host